# How to insert dictionary items into a PostgreSQL table

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, key-value, psycopg2

So I've connected my Postgresql database into Python with Psycopg2, and I've pulled two specific columns to update. The first column I have used as the keys in a Python dictionary, and I have run some functions on the second one and use the results as the values in the dictionary. Now what I want to do is add those values back into Postgresql table as a new column, but I want them to pair with the correct keys they are paired with in the dictionary. Essentially, I want to take dictionary values and insert them as a new column and pick which "key" in the Postgresql table they belong to (however, I don't want to manually assign them, because, well, there's hopefully a better way).

Postgresql Table

```
     |col1   |col2  |col3   | ... | coln  
row1 | a1    | b1   | c1    | ... | n1  
row2 | a2    | b2   | c2    | ... | n2  
...  | ...   | ...  | ...   | ... | n...  
rowm | am    | bm   | cm    | ... | nm
```

This is the dictionary I made in Python, where `f()` is a series of functions ran on variable:

```
{ 
    a1 : f(c1),  
    a2 : f(c2),   
    ... : ... 
}
```

Now my goal is to add the values column back into my table so that it corresponds to the original keys. Ideally, to look something like this:

```
     |col1|col2|col3| ... |newcol| coln  
row1 | a1 | b1 | c1 | ... | f(c1)| n1  
row2 | a2 | b2 | c2 | ... | f(c2)| n2  
...  | ...| ...| ...| ... |  ... | n...  
rowm | am | bm | cm | ... | f(cm)| nm
```

I know I can insert the column into the table, but not sure how to pair it with keys. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Is `col1` the primary key for the db table? (it is the key in the python dict)

Comment: @joop, no col1 is not the primary key in the db because there are actually pairs of each value in column 1. There is a column record_id, which is basically correlates with row number, which can uniquely identify each row (I think that's the primary key, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an `UPDATE` statement something like the following:

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect('your connection string')
cur = connection.cursor()
# add newcol
cur.execute('ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN newcol text;')
con.commit()
for k,v in your_dict.iteritems():
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE your_table 
                         SET newcol = (%s) 
                       WHERE col1 = (%s);''',(v,k))
    conn.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Update all the rows in a single query. First turn the dictionary into a list of tuples:

```
l = [(k,v) for k,v in my_dict.items()]
```

A Python list of tuples is adapted to an array of records by Psycopg. Then `unnest` the array in the `from` clause:

```
query = '''
    update t
    set colX = s.val::text
    from unnest(%s) s (key integer, val unknown)
    where t.col1 = s.key
'''

print cursor.mogrify(query, (l,))
cursor.execute(query, (l,))
```

Records returned from `unnest` need to have their elements types declared. For string values is it necessary to declare their type as `unknown` and cast to the appropriate type at assignment or comparing time. For all other types just declare them as usual.